# Access controller's function from other controller

Tags: ember.js

I have two controllers as follow.

```
App.CreditIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    viewAll: function(){
        //Some code
    }
})


App.CreditVoucherController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['creditIndex'],
    viewAllVoucher: function(){
        this.get('controller.controllers.creditIndex').viewAll();
    }
})
```

I was trying to access `viewAll` function from `CreditVoucherController`. But it didn't worked.
What is the way do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a to access another controller via the `controllers property`:

```
App.CreditVoucherController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['creditIndex'],
    viewAllVoucher: function(){
        this.get('controllers.creditIndex').viewAll();
    }
});
```